# Quandl LimitExceededError @ first request although using API

Tags: python, api, finance, trading

as probably many others i got very comfortable with the Yahoo Finance API. Now I got finally around to consider alternatives. I signed up to Quandl, got my KEY. so far so good..

When I tried to request a very basic data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

QUANDL_KEY = '{dnyYEnFxwxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}'
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = QUANDL_KEY
df_quandl = quandl.get(dataset='WIKI/AAPL',start_date='2000-01-01',end_date='2010-12-31')
```

I get the following error message:

> LimitExceededError: (Status 429)
>   (Quandl Error QELx01) You have exceeded the anonymous user limit of 50
>   calls per day. To make more calls today, please register for a free
>   Quandl account and then include your API key with your requests.

I have activated my account and I am definitively within the allowed amount of requests. 
I am probably overlooking something trivial.. Can someone help?
Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same question and it worked out by just writing

`quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'i6k_ftcyxxxxxxxxxxx'
mydata_01 = quandl.get("FRED/GDP")`

Don' forget to confirm your email or an error will appear again...